# Find number of ways to select $10$ balls such that at least one red ball and one blue ball are selected.

Tags: combinatorics

Consider $4$ boxes, where each box contains $3$ red balls and $2$ blue balls. Assume that all $20$ balls are distinct. In how many different ways can $10$ balls be chosen from these $4$ boxes so that from each box at least one red ball and one blue ball are chosen?

(A) 21816

(B) 85536

(C) 12096

(D) 156816

My Attempt

I tried to take different cases

(2,2)(1,1)(1,1)(1,1) $\times 4$

(1,2)(2,1)(1,1)(1,1) $\times 6\times 2$

(3,1)(3,1)(1,1)(1,1) $\times 6$

(1,2)(1,2)(1,1)(1,1) $\times 6$

(R,B) denotes number of red balls and blue balls chosen from the bag.

But it appears I am missing certain cases

Comment: Your notation isn't clear.  At least, I can't sort out what $(3,1)(3,1)(1,1)(1,1)$ might mean.  That would appear to be $12$ balls, no?

Comment: $(3,1)(3,1)(1,1)(1,1)$ is not a case--it uses $12$ balls. You need cases of $(3,1)(1,1)(1,1)(1,1)$ and $(2,1)(2,1)(1,1)(1,1)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we need to choose at least one red and blue ball out of every box, $8$ of $10$ places are already chosen.

I come across the following five possibilities (noted similarly with the R,B-pairs):

$$a: (3,1),(1,1),(1,1),(1,1) \\
b: (2,1),(2,1),(1,1),(1,1) \\
c: (2,1),(1,2),(1,1),(1,1) \\
d: (2,2),(1,1),(1,1),(1,1) \\
e: (1,2),(1,2),(1,1),(1,1)$$

Now you need to consider that all balls are distinct. This means $(1,1)$ actually represents $3\cdot 2$ and $(2,2)$ represents $3\cdot 1$ possibilities! You can also swap the boxes with each other, so for example in case $a$ by swapping the boxes we need to multiply everything by $4$ resulting in the following number of possibilities:

$$
a: (2 \cdot 6 \cdot 6 \cdot 6) \cdot 4 \\
b: (6 \cdot 6 \cdot 6 \cdot 6) \cdot 6 \\
c: (6 \cdot 3 \cdot 6 \cdot 6) \cdot 12 \\
d: (3 \cdot 6 \cdot 6 \cdot 6) \cdot 4 \\
e: (3 \cdot 3 \cdot 6 \cdot 6) \cdot 6 \\
$$
resulting in a total of
$1728+7776+7776+2592+1944=21816$ cases.

This means $(A)$ is correct.

Comment: Can there be some other approach, say using lattice points

Comment: I'm not aware of another method using lattice points. Do you have a similar "counting possibilities"-example where lattice points are useful?