# Ways of choosing a set of unique balls from a set of boxes

Tags: combinatorics

Consider 4 boxes, where each box contains 3 red balls and 2 blue balls. Assume that all 20 balls are distinct. In how many different ways can 10 balls be chosen from these 4 boxes so that from each box at least one red ball and one blue ball are chosen?
(A) 21816
(B) 85536
(C) 12096
(D) 156816

I tried to solve this problem in the following way:
Suppose we select 1 red ball and 1 blue ball from each box 1st.
So this can be done in *${3 \choose 1}{2 \choose 1}$ ways per box*
and hence in total it can be done in $({3 \choose 1}{2 \choose 1})^4$ many ways. Now we are left with 12 balls and we need to choose 2 from this set. This can of course be done in ${12 \choose 2}$ ways.

Thus total ways to pick 10 balls = $({3 \choose 1}{2 \choose 1})^4{12 \choose 2}$ ways = 85536 ways

However, the correct answer is (A) 21816.
I cannot understand which cases are additionally included in my solution. Please explain what is wrong with this solution.

Comment: I am closing this question as a duplicate since the person who posed the linked question also made the error you made.  If you would like further elaboration on your error, please let me know.  Another solution to the problem can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4520907/find-number-of-ways-to-select-10-balls-such-that-at-least-one-red-ball-and-one).